# Reliability of Fluentd td-agent

Tags: fluentd

This question is regarding the reliability of the fluentd.

I have three nodes. On node1 and node2, application is running with its logging in separate file. Node3 is the logserver where we used to keep logs.

I install td-agent on N1 and N2 and log collector td-agent on N3. If td-agent gets crashes on N1, somehow, how the logs will be collected of N1. Will the logs of N1 get lost?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your log collecting structure.
For example if you setup your td-agent to tail local N1 log file and use pos_file attribute to mark last processed row, after the crash it will continue from the section where it left.

But if your logs a just a stream and you are collecting it from sock then you should setup some kind of alert to be notified when your logs stopped working.

Also there is a good example how to setup high availability td-agent https://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/td-agent-high-availability